# How can I make Solana stake transaction with python?

Tags: blockchain, solana, staking

How can I develop Solana staking with python?
How can I make Solana stake transaction with python?
Has anyone done it yet?
Is there any resource for help?

Answer (score 0):

You can make some stake program instructions using the stake pool python bindings. You can find the source code for them at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/stake-pool/py/stake and some tests exercising the logic at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/stake-pool/py/tests/test_stake.py